# Wrong TOC page number with starred part + \addcontentsline

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, books, parts, starred-version

When using an unnumbered part (`\part*`), added to TOC using `\addcontentsline`, the page number for the part page is wrong.

See this MWE :

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \part*{First part}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{First part} 
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
\end{document}
```

The "Part 1" page is page 3, but the TOC says 5, like the beginning of the first chapter. If we adds `hyperref` the anchor for the internal link will be similar (page 5 instead of page 3).

It seems basic, but I can't figure out how to fix this behavior, and to my surprise I've found no answer, here or in regular latex manuals… Does someone know what is going wrong here?

Comment: `\cleardoublepage \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{First part} \part*{First Part}`

Comment: Try `\part*{First part\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{First part}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that `\part*`, unlike `\chapter*`, not only starts a new page and prints the heading on it, it also starts another new page after the heading. In double-sided printing, this page remains empty, so another new page is started. Only then your `\addcontentsline` statement is executed and thus comes two pages too late.

To solve this, you should, as indicated in Ulrike's comment, first start a new right page, then place the `\addcontentsline` statement and only after that the heading with `\part*`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{First part} 
    \part*{First part}
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
\end{document}
```

`\addcontentsline` before the heading also has the advantage that when `hyperref` is used, the link actually points before the heading instead of after it.

BTW: The KOMA-Script class `scrbook` has an additional command `\addpart`, that is used like `\chapter*` but automatically adds a toc entry:

```
\documentclass[emulatestandardclasses]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \addpart{First part}
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
\end{document}
```

I've used option `emulatestandardclasses` to emulate the lookalike of the standard `book` class. Without the option page header and footer and the chapter headings would be different.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Indeed that works!